# VB.NET Multiple strings from a listbox?

Tags: vb.net, string, listbox

Lets shy my listbox has 3 names Anna,Sam and Wendy how would I go about writing those in a text file like this.

Name #1 is Anna
Name #2 is Sam
Name #3 is Wendy!

An example of how I need my code to look

[image]

Comment: What specifically are you having problems with. Please show us what your code looks like so far

Comment: I'm trying to write multiple blocks of text in a text file and I'm using the listbox to hold all the strings I need to put in those blocks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to iterate through your `ListBox` collection like this. I am just printing this to the Output Window in Visual Studio.

```
For Each lbi As String In ListBox1.Items
    Debug.Print(Chr(9) + Chr(9) + "ent = maps\ (" + Chr(34) + lbi.ToString() + Chr(34) + ");" + vbCrLf)
Next
```

For writing to a file you could use something like this, I am using `File.AppendallLines` so that it will not overwrite the existing file you could use `File.WriteAllLines` which would overwrite it.

```
Dim myList As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)
For Each lbi As String In ListBox1.Items
    myList.Add(Chr(9) + Chr(9) + "ent = maps\ (" + Chr(34) + lbi.ToString() + Chr(34) + ");" + vbCrLf)
Next
File.AppendAllLines("C:\temp\myDataFile.txt", myList)
```

Comment: I can't use "File" for some reason

Comment: Make sure you put Imports System.IO at the top of your Code File before your Class definition

Comment: Its still not writing anything to the txt file, Am I missing something?

Comment: No if you put the Imports in and can use the File class without an error it should work, I tested it to verify that it worked before posting, what is the path that you are using?, try adding the code that you have so far to your question.

Comment: It works in C:\ but not Program Files (x86) I'm guessing its some sort of space issue?

Comment: @user3478897 If your are running Windows vista or above, you are running into a UAC problem, writing to the program directory is strongly discouraged. I usually put it into the ProgramData directory in a specific folder for my program, making sure that I have the security permissions in place to write there.

Comment: I have UAC turned off, I remember when doing something in CMD you had to change the Path a bit so CMD could read it.

Comment: It is still not considered good practice anymore to write to your Program Directory, also you can check the security settings for your Program Directory to make sure that you have write permissions

Comment: Well the problem is that I have to write my files under program files.

Comment: It should work if you do what I said in the second part of my last comment. In your Program Files directory right click on your directory select properties, go to the security tab, click on the edit button, select Users then go to the bottom of the dialog box and select allow for Full Control. Apply your changes then try it again.